# Crash in viewDidLoad() when registering observers

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I've a crash occurring in `viewDidLoad`. I'm not able to figure out why it's happening. Below is crash trace and all the code.

[image: crash]

```
class WriteTestimonialViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addPurpleBackground()

        title = "Write Testimonial"

        testimonialTextView.clearTextView(text: "Type testimonial")

        // Setup keyboard event
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        // Dismiss keyboard
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }

    // Setup keyboard event
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){

        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

 }

extension UIViewController {

    // Dismiss keyboard on touch
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

func addPurpleBackground() {
    let imageViewBackground = UIImageView()
    imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "bgimage")

    imageViewBackground.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds = true
    imageViewBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.insertSubview(imageViewBackground, at: 0)

    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[imageViewBackground]|",
                                                       options: [],
                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                       views: ["imageViewBackground": imageViewBackground]))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[imageViewBackground]|",
                                                       options: [],
                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                       views: ["imageViewBackground": imageViewBackground]))
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the debug console - any errors or messages being logged there? Usually when there is a crash you'll also have some detail down there to help explain what's going on.

Comment: It's happening in production app. The trace I've shown is from crashlog in xCode Organizer. It's random crash. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Your app can crash because you are posting notifications under `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I'm adding observer not posting, is that what you meant? How to fix it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think would be better to register for notifications in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`, you would be interested in the notifications only if the view is actually displayed. If you keep it in `viewDidLoad` can happen sometimes that the view has been loaded but is not immediately appeared on the screen.

Also [From iOS 9 you don't need anymore to manually remove observer.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html)

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and
>   NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to
>   registered observers that may be deallocated

Comment: I think you may be right. I've already moved them in viewWillAppear. I've also removed notifications in viewWillDisappear. I hope this will prevent crash.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the documentation quote where it states that you might not need to manually remove notifications as from iOS 9

Comment: Tx for clarification on removing observer.